# localstorage event listener not working on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to listen to localstorage changes and perform some operation on change.

```
$(window).on("storage", this.handleLocalStorageChange);
```

This works on IE-10 and IE-11 but doesn't work on **Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0**. Can anyone enlighten me on why this is happening and what is the workaround for this?

Comment: are you trying to listen to changes from the same browsing context where you are making those changes? Or from a different browsing context on the same domain? Or from a different browsing context on a different domain?

Comment: note: [MDN's compat table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event#browser_compatibility) says support for storage events was added to Edge in version 15

Answer (score 1):

Per the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event)

> Note: [storage events] won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made. Pages on other domains can't access the same storage objects.

Comment: hm. while this may be useful info in general, the asker hasn't provided any information that says whether or not they were actually trying to listen to this event in the same browsing context where they are making the changes.

Comment: That's true. I assumed that the `window` was the global one. It may also be the classic case of IE being behind as you pointed out.